# Get 1 random record from Tarantool space

Tags: random, lua, tarantool, tarantool-cartridge

I have query with 2 conditions which return 1 record every request 1by1 as inserted in space

```
box.space.extensions.index.secondary:select(
        {city, 0},
        {limit=1}
    )
```

Sample:

```
{1}
{2}
{3}
```

I need to get random record every request.
Sample:

```
{3}
{1}
{2}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to tarantool API, `select` returns array of tuples, so that's a regular Lua table you can manipulate by yourself.
If you want to randomize the content in the request you need `table.Shuffle`.
If you want to get one random item from the request, you can use `tbl[math.random(#tbl)]`.

Here is [example](https://www.programming-idioms.org/idiom/10/shuffle-a-list/1313/lua) of `table.Shuffle` code:

```lua
function table.Shuffle(tbl)
    for i = #tbl, 2, -1 do
        local j = math.random(i)
        tbl[i], tbl[j] = tbl[j], tbl[i]
    end
end
```